# I need a data grid which should perform server side paging, sorting and filtering and editing?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am working in angularjs, I need a grid which should perform server side paging, sorting and filtering and editing, currently I am using angular ui-grid, but lately I have realized that I am not using any features that Ui-grid is providing, as I have applied sorting paging and filtering externally, Can someone suggest me what should be my approach.

Comment: You can tell ui-grid to disable internal paging via the grid options. http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.pagination.api:GridOptions. You would need to set up a ```paginationChanged``` function to tell it the new data and count. For externally filtering, http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/321_singleFilter shows an example of using external filtering.

Comment: I should use ui-grid?